# which classes we should manually create a bean for and when does it work automatically

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring & spring boot

We create a bean for example of Weblient.Builder to use it for auto wiring in other classes.

```
@Bean   
public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
    return WebClient.builder();
}
```

What I do not understand is why this is needed for some classes and not others, just auto wire is enough for some other class types and the spring boot framework seem to create the objects automatically. Why is that ? and secondly how do we know which classes we should manually create a bean for which classes spring boot does it automatically.

Comment: It is not just about object creation there are a few other things. When to create an object? What should be the scope of the object? Do we need to create a new object every time or use the existing one? Is there anything to be done when a bean is always created or destroyed? Imagine doing these by yourself then imagine using a battle-tested framework to do it for you. You should dive deep into Spring framework before starting Spring boot.